# Android Studio: can not git add new sub package

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have a strange problem with Android Studio. I checked out into a brand new branch. There I create a sub package to an existing main package. Inside that package I create some classes.

Essentially it looks like this

```
com.package.stuff   
 |
  somepackage
  |
   out<---- This one is newly created
    |
     Files.java <--- new classes inside package
     More.java
```

Normally new files would be highlighted in red color. When I move the classes outside the package it highlights it as green - unwatched.

No matter how much I try Android Studio would not let me to `git add` these new files inside the new package.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I tried it with the git terminal and it gave me the actual reason for that.

The subpackage name was `out` and in my `.gitignore` I ignored `/out`. Apparently it doesn't consider if it has a different path.

So well, I renamed the package and now it works again. Lesson learned, don't name your package for something you are about to ignore...